# German visa and Blue Card process

Tags: visas, europe, india, germany, schengen-visas

I have an offer from a German employer and the salary is 63K Euros. I am in India right now, and want to understand the correct visa process and ability to work in Germany.

During a conversation with an HR person, I was told to obtain a travel visa which is valid for 3 months. When this visa is granted, I'm supposed to travel to Germany and complete my joining formalities. After that, they will initiate a process for obtaining my Blue Card, which will allow me to remain in Germany and work.

I have not heard of this procedure before. I did some research on the Blue Card, and it looked alright, but I'm still concerned.

Here are the answers that I want to know.

1. What kind of visa would be given for travel from India to Germany? Is it the same as Schengen visa?
2. Is this visa process legitimate? By that I mean, the process of getting a visa to travel from India to Germany and then applying for a Bluecard.
3. How much money would be required to be shown in account to obtain the visa for travel from India to Germany?

Comment: Updated the question for specific doubts which I have

Comment: would this question be more for the expatriates site ?

Comment: Yes it is a legitimate path. Shengen visa >  job seekers visa > blue card. Since you have a job offer / contract in hand it shouldn't be too difficult. But you should schedule your Bürgeramt and  Ausländerbehörde appointments well in advance if possible.

Comment: Feel free to get in contact if you need more info.

Comment: I am in a very similar position and I would like know more about this @ksav.

Comment: Same situation with me, what did you do? did you apply Blue card in your home country or after arrival to Germany? And when did you initiate the blue card application processes after arrival to Germany? after 2-3 weeks? Please guide?